# How can I assign category of sent mail in outlook vba?

Tags: vba, outlook

I followed the below example:

https://www.slipstick.com/developer/create-a-new-message-using-vba/

I want to categorize mail automatically when I send an email by macro.
but, sometimes category is in category.

For example, suppose, "Report" Category is under "Company" Category.

How can i assign my sent mail to "Report" Category in "Company" Category?
Here is my code. it is almost same with the example code.

```
Public Sub CreateNewMessage()
Dim objMsg As MailItem

Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With objMsg
  .To = "Alias@domain.com"
  .CC= "Alias2@domain.com"
  .BCC = "Alias3@domain.com"
  .Subject = "This is the subject"
  .Categories = "Test"
  .VotingOptions = "Yes;No;Maybe;"
  .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain ' send plain text message
  .Importance = olImportanceHigh
  .Sensitivity = olConfidential
  .Attachments.Add ("path-to-file.docx")

 ' Calculate a date using DateAdd or enter an explicit date
  .ExpiryTime = DateAdd("m", 6, Now) '6 months from now
  .DeferredDeliveryTime = #8/1/2012 6:00:00 PM#

  .Display
End With
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow, could you please clarify what you mean when saying "category is in category" ?

Comment: outlook's category can have category under itself. I meant that.

Answer (score 5):

Categories in Outlook is a flat list, a category cannot be a child (or a parent) of another category. That being said, you can assign multiple categories to any item - just separate them with ";"

```
.Categories = "Test;Report;Some Other Category"
```